# Writing test cases for custom Iterator

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, iterator

I created a custom iterator which accepts multiple iterators within its constructor and produces alternate output for an example  constructed with three iterators:

> [a,b,c], [1,2] and [x,y,z]

The iterator should produce the elements in this order

> a, 1, x, b, 2, y, c, z

My iterator code:

```
package alternate.iterator;

import java.util.Iterator;

 /**Alternates on the given iterators.*/
 public class ImprovedAlternateIterator<E> implements Iterator {

/**Stores the iterators which are to be alternated on.*/
private Iterator<E>[] iterators;

/**The index of iterator, which has the next element.*/
private int nextIterator = 0;

/**Initializes a new AlternatingIterator object.
 * Stores the iterators in the iterators field.
 * Finds the first iterator with an available element.*/
public ImprovedAlternateIterator(Iterator<E> ... iterators) {
    this.iterators = iterators;

    if (!iterators[0].hasNext())
        findNextIterator();
}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {

    return iterators[nextIterator].hasNext();
}

@Override
public Object next() {
    E element = iterators[nextIterator].next();

    findNextIterator();

    return element;
}

/**Steps on iterators, until one has next element.
 * It does not step on them infinitely, stops when
 * the lastly used iterator is reached.*/
private void findNextIterator() {
    int currentIterator = nextIterator;

    // Finding iterator with element remaining.
    do {
        stepNextIterator();
    } while (!iterators[nextIterator].hasNext() && nextIterator != currentIterator);
    // If it gets around to the same iterator, then there is no iterator with element.
}

/**Increases the nextIterator value without indexing out of bounds.*/
private void stepNextIterator() {
    nextIterator = (nextIterator + 1) % iterators.length;
}
}
```

Main class:

```
package alternate.iterator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class MainApplication {

public static <E> void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.addAll(Arrays.asList( "A", "B","C"));

    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list2.addAll(Arrays.asList( "x", "y","z"));

    ArrayList<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list3.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2));

    // ListIterator to traverse the list
    ListIterator iterator1 = list1.listIterator();
    ListIterator iterator2 = list2.listIterator();
    ListIterator iterator3 = list3.listIterator();

    ImprovedAlternateIterator <E> l = new ImprovedAlternateIterator<E>(iterator1,iterator2,iterator3);

    while (l.hasNext()) {
       System.out.print(l.next()+ " ");
    }
}
}
```

***How can I write test cases for testing the functionality of the hasNext() and next() of the custom iterator?***

I am really confused and don't know what to test and how to write a test case. I would like to learn more about testing and if you can show me by writing a sample test case then that would be really helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Test First (or Test Driven Development (TDD) approach. Put you code to the side for a moment.

Write the shortest thing that compiles (without warnings - you're missing the type argument on `Iterator` and the return type of `next` is wrong):

```
package alternate.iterator;

import java.util.*;

/**Alternates on the given iterators.*/
public class ImprovedAlternateIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {
    /**Initializes a new AlternatingIterator object.
     * Stores the iterators in the iterators field.
     * Finds the first iterator with an available element.*/
    public ImprovedAlternateIterator(Iterator<E> ... iterators) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public E next() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now write your simplest possible test. Make the code pass in the simplest possible way. Refactor if necessary. Check test again. Repeat until done.

You might notice your interface is incomplete, for instance the constructor parameter should be `Iterator<? extends E>` - no need to fix without a test first. You are missing `remove` (it has become a default method unfortunately).

It's not an approach **I** would usually use first, but I think it's very useful here.

Comment: Great spot on the `Iterator<? extends E>`, very clever observation. On the TDD front, I'd love to have a chat about your thoughts although I recognise this isn't the forum. E.G. if I were in an interview and asked to impl a stack, I'd TDD. In real life I'll TDD a calc or data structure. Often though, I find my code is a work in progress and I'm solving problems as I go. I write some code, write some tests, repeat. I've found that TDDing the minimal compilation unit is a time sink before I know what it's going to look like. How do you approach TDD when faced with unknowns?

Comment: Tom, just checked your profile - you're in Edinburgh too. Do you go to the Java User Groups at NCR? Hit me up if you fancy a beer with a couple of Nucleus devs. robertandrewbain at googlemail dot com

Comment: @RobertBain Thanks. I go to edjug most months (unless I'm away or doing something else).

Answer (score 0):

The following example provides two sample test cases using junit and / or hamcrest. Hamcrest offers several benefits but essentially increases the readability of the code. It's worth reading up on.

Delete the assertions from the one you don't want to use.

```
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.nucleusfinancial.ImprovedAlternateIterator;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class ImprovedAlternateIteratorTest {

    @Test
    public void hasNext_returns_next_from_first_iterator() {
        ImprovedAlternateIterator iterator = new ImprovedAlternateIterator(List.of("foo").iterator());
        // junit
        assertEquals(iterator.next(), "foo");
        // hamcrest
        assertThat(iterator.next(), is("foo"));
    }

    @Test
    public void hasNext_returns_next_from_second_iterator_after_first_iterator_has_been_iterated_over() {
        ImprovedAlternateIterator iterator = new ImprovedAlternateIterator(List.of("foo").iterator(), List.of("bar").iterator());
        //junit
        assertEquals(iterator.next(), "foo");
        assertEquals(iterator.next(), "bar");
        //hamcrest
        assertThat(iterator.next(), is("foo"));
        assertThat(iterator.next(), is("bar"));
    }
}
```

Regarding test cases, start with the good case - does it do what it's meant to? Think about boundary conditions. What happens if you put in something too large, or too small, or null, or empty etc. Ensure you test all branches - a code coverage tool is useful for this.

Comment: Hi Robert thank you for help but i never used hamcrest before how can i test the functionality of the hasnext and next method in a simple manner?

Answer (score 0):

Before testing your Iterator implementation you have to consider what is **public API** of your class. And cover contracts of this API.

In your case you have 2 public methods: `hasNext()`, `next()`.

I want to add that for any iterator implementation `hasNext()` should be idempotent. The result should be the same even if you call it 1, 10 or 100 times.

Also, you have to consider how to manage your test class. What should be test data, how you have to access it from different test cases and how to relieve resources after tests execution, etc.

Keep in mind that Junit execution doesn't have a strict sequence for tests execution.
It can call tests like

`test1()`, `test2()`, `test3()`

or

`test2()`, `test1()`...

Therefore you can't check for `next()`: at one method that first element from all iterators is retrieved and at do the same for the second element from another method.

Here is an example some skeleton for testing your iterator implementation:

```
private ImprovedAlternateIterator<Iterator> improvedIterator;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<String> list1 = Lists.newArrayList("A", "B", "C");
    ArrayList<String> list2 = Lists.newArrayList("x", "y", "z");
    ArrayList<Integer> list3 = Lists.newArrayList(1, 2);

    ListIterator iterator1 = list1.listIterator();
    ListIterator iterator2 = list2.listIterator();
    ListIterator iterator3 = list3.listIterator();

    improvedIterator = new ImprovedAlternateIterator<Iterator>(iterator1, iterator2, iterator3);
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    improvedIterator = null;
}

/**
 * check that hasNext() is idempotent -> even if you call it 1 or 10 times the result should be the same
 */
@Test
public void testHasNextForAlternateIterator() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        assertTrue(improvedIterator.hasNext());
    }
}

/**
 * check that next() for iterator
 * it should return first element per each iterator
 */
@Test
public void testNextForAlternateIterator() {
    String expectedFromFirstIterator = "A";
    String expectedFromSecondIterator = "x";
    int expectedFromThirdIterator = 1;

    assertEquals(expectedFromFirstIterator, improvedIterator.next());
    assertEquals(expectedFromSecondIterator, improvedIterator.next());
    assertEquals(expectedFromThirdIterator, improvedIterator.next());

    String expected2FromFirstIterator = "B";
    String expected2FromSecondIterator = "y";
    int expected2FromThirdIterator = 2;

    assertEquals(expected2FromFirstIterator, improvedIterator.next());
    assertEquals(expected2FromSecondIterator, improvedIterator.next());
    assertEquals(expected2FromThirdIterator, improvedIterator.next());

    // you can omit following section if you don't need to cover it
    String expected3FromFirstIterator = "C";
    String expected3FromSecondIterator = "z";

    assertEquals(expected3FromFirstIterator, improvedIterator.next());
    assertEquals(expected3FromSecondIterator, improvedIterator.next());
}
```

Quite useful is to add some informative message if the test failed:

> assertEquals("First element from first iterator isn't retrieved", expected, actual);

Also, consider negative cases when you retrieved all elements from your iterator or it is empty. What exactly should be returned? Some exception or default value. You can add cases for covering them as well.